# How can I send raw audio data to Bing Speech using the C# SDK?

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services

I'm trying to create an application that's going to receive raw audio data from another service and send it to the Bing Speech API for recognition. Based on the [sample available on the Github repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/ProjectOxford-ClientSDK/blob/master/Speech/SpeechToText/Windows/samples/SpeechRecognitionServiceExample/MainWindow.xaml.cs), I've written the following code (using the C# SDK).

```
private static void sendFileData(string filename)
{
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Setting up audio data format.");
        SpeechAudioFormat audioFormat = SpeechAudioFormat.create16BitPCMFormat(sampleRate); // sampleRate = 8000
        asrClient.SendAudioFormat(audioFormat);

        int bytesRead = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        try
        {
            do
            {
                // Get more Audio data into byte buffer.
                bytesRead = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                // Send audio data to service. 
                asrClient.SendAudio(buffer, bytesRead);
            }
            while (bytesRead > 0);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            // We are done sending audio. Final recognition results will arrive in OnResponseReceived event call.
            asrClient.EndAudio();
        }
    }
}
```

The only difference is that I'm setting up the audio format, since it's not a WAVE file. However, the recognition results I receive are completely wrong <strike>(I've tested this file on the REST API before, and it worked as intended)</strike>. Moreover, if I use this same code and send a WAVE file instead, I get the right result. Am I doing something wrong when setting the audio format? Does anyone know of a sample code for this kind of situation?

**-- Edit --**

As suggested by @NikolayShmyrev, here's a link to the test file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7pbKnD-4XNMTlJudlZqTFNCR0k/view?usp=sharing

The audio was sampled at 8000 Hz and saved as 16 bits signed-integer PCM data. The utterance is in Brazilian Portuguese (pt-br) and should be recognized as "eu quero uma pizza de calabresa".

Comment: Most likely the audio format you send is wrong. I.e. the raw audio has some different sample rate or sample representation. You can share the sample of the file to get help.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev I thought so too, but sending the file via REST I get the right result. As far as I can tell, this seems to be a problem with the way I set the audio format using the SDK. Just to be sure, I've tested the audio with sox. It's 16 bit signed-integer mono-channel, sampled at 8000 Hz.

Comment: It is not quite clear how you tested raw audio with sox.

Comment: I just used sox to playback the file using the settings I mentioned. But I did a double-check, and it seems I only got WAV (not the raw data) to work through the REST API. So it might be something related to the sample representation, as you mentioned. I'll update my question to include a link to the test file.